# JS: How to simplify over-precise numbers of a list while keeping n meaningful digits?

Tags: javascript, math

I want to clean up a whole, big JSON full of over-precise numbers.

Given numbers  with both a large numbers of decimals and a great variability, such:

```
set 1:
w: 984.4523354645713, 
h: 003.87549531298341238;

set 2:
x: 0.00023474987546783901386284892,
y: 0.000004531457539283543;
```

Given I want to simplify them, and store them with the same precision, let's say 4 meaningful digits, aligned on the biggest.

I want something such :

```
set 1:
w: 984.5,
h: 003.9;

set 2:
x: 0.0002347,
y: 0.0000045;
```

for all my hundreds sets and thousands numbers.

**How to simplify numbers of this list while keeping n meaningful digits (aligned on the biggest) ?**

Comment: Wouldn't `003.87549531298341238` be rounded to `3.9`?

Comment: yes indeed ! typo mistake !

Comment: Okay, another question, can numbers be greater than 1000? And if so, what should happen to the number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XwSt8/).

```
// create our list:
var width  = 984.4523354645713,
    height = 003.87549531298341238;
// pick the biggest:
var max = Math.abs( Math.max( width, height) );
// How many digits we keep ?
if      ( max < 10000&& max >= 1000 ) { digits = 0; } 
else if ( max < 1000 && max >= 100  ) { digits = 1; }
else if ( max < 100  && max >= 10   ) { digits = 2; }
else if ( max < 10   && max >= 1    ) { digits = 3; }
else if ( max < 1    && max >= 0.1  ) { digits = 4; }
else if ( max < 0.1  && max >= 0.01 ) { digits = 5; }
else if ( max < 0.01  && max >= 0.001){ digits = 6; };
// Simplify accordingly:
console.log("w: " + width + ", h: "+ height +", w_(rounded): "+ width.toFixed(digits) +", and h_(rounded): " + height.toFixed(digits) );
```

**INPUT:**

```
w: 984.4523354645713, 
h: 003.87549531298341238;
```

**OUTPUT (nicely aligned!):**

```
w_(rounded): 984.5, 
h_(rounded):   3.9;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Massive Edit**

This function wil do what you want:

```
function get_meaningful_digit_pos(digits, val1, val2) {
    var max = Math.max.apply(null, [val1, val2].map(function(n) {
            return Math.abs(n);
        })),
        digit = Math.pow(10, digits),
        index = 0;

    // For positive numbers, check how many numbers there are
    // before the dot, then return the negative digits left.
    if (max > 0) {
        while (digit > 1) {
            if (max >= digit) {
                return -digits;
            }

            digits--;
            digit /= 10;
        }
    }

    // Loop 15 times at max; after that in JavaScript a double
    // loses its precision.
    for (; index < 15 - digits; index++) {
        if (0 + max.toFixed(index) !== 0) {
            return index + digits;
        }
    }
}
```

It returns the position of the first digits you want to have, with 0 being the dot itself.

Here are some tests I ran:

```
get_meaningful_digit_pos(4, 1234, 0.0);          // -3
get_meaningful_digit_pos(4, 12.000001234, 0.0);  // -1
get_meaningful_digit_pos(4, 1.234, 0.0);         // 0
get_meaningful_digit_pos(4, 0.1234, 1.0);        // 0
get_meaningful_digit_pos(4, 0.0000001234, 0.0);  // 7
get_meaningful_digit_pos(4, 0.0000001234, 10.0); // -1
```

Comment: Note: your approach is like `.toFixed(3)`. My issue is more on keeping various set of numbers aligned upon the biggest of the set, which then also ask an `If` loop.

Comment: @Hugolpz I'm sorry, I don't fully understand what exactly you're asking. What do you mean by _"aligned upon the biggest of the set"_? Do you mean you want to grab the biggest value of your JSON data first?

Comment: I reedited the question. It's basically a case where the data have to be simplified. Each row should keep 4 meaningful digits, based on the biggest item.

Comment: @broxier: I already have a solution, but it's always fun to see and other way to do so.

Comment: @Hugolpz It took some time, but was fun to do! I rewrote my entire answer, hope this helps. :)